# Prove that there is a natural injection $U \otimes V \rightarrow E \otimes F $

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

­­Hello everyone I found the following statement in my lecture :

> Let $U$ a subset of $E$ and $V$ a subset of $F$ , so there is a natural injection $U \otimes V \rightarrow E \otimes F  $

But I don't exactly see why it's true , and what they mean with natural injection ? Any help would be a lot welcomed thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear mugiwara,  are $U,E,V,F$ vector space?

Comment: Hello @ParesseuxNguyen , yes they're all vector space and with finite dimension my bad sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, the map $U \times V \to E \otimes F$ given by $(u,v) \mapsto u \otimes v$ is bilinear, so, by the universal property there is a linear map $U \otimes V \to E \otimes F$ such that $u \otimes v \mapsto u \otimes v$.